# How to run ftp.bat by pressing vba button in excell?

Tags: excel, batch-file, ftp, dataset, mainframe

I am trying to automate data extraction from mainframe and I've tried the solution below but it didn't work. Instead it erased the contents of the FtpLogin2.bat file.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c D:\user\MyDocs\Downloads_FTP\FtpLogin2.bat",    
vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

The content of ftplogin2.bat

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF 
open ip user
password ped 
get 'mainframe_dataset' pc_dataset.txt
```

What I'm trying to do is to build a form where I have an input. That input is the name of the mainframe file I want to extract. That data shoukld then appear in another worksheet of that excel book.I mean to automate that process by having a text field and a submit button, which should trigger the FTP in the macro.

Is there  away to do that?

Comment: What is in ftplogin2.bat? What happens if you only put echo hello > log.txt in that file? Do you get a log.txt file?

Comment: @ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
   open ip
   user
   password
   pwd
   get 'mainframe_dataset' pc_dataset.txt


I didn't try that. Now I can only try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem using environ() in this case; I'm not sure why.

Use `Shell("cmd.exe /c D:\user\MyDocs\Downloads_FTP\FtpLogin2.bat"`

This should work on any version of Windows after 3.11.